# CSS3 transitions, using translateX + translateY set to positive values, do not appear to transition properly

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm currently trying to implement some CSS transition effects on a set of different panels, to give the appearance that they are "sliding in" from off screen.  I want them each to appear in a different direction (e.g. top to bottom, left to right, etc.)

Presumably, to do bottom to top and right to left, I would just want to set translateX or translateY, but with a positive value, rather than negative. And then for all of them, I would just translate the value to 0 when I want them to appear on screen.

Here is a really simplified version of [what I am trying to do](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwVGYO):

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div id="about" class="panel">
  <h2>About</h2>
  <p>I'm Mike and I don't know!</p>
  <a href="#">Close</a>
</div>

<div id="projects" class="panel">
  <h2>Projects</h2>
  <p>Here are some projects I have worked on.</p>
  <a href="#">Close</a>
</div>

<div id="contact" class="panel">
  <h2>Contact</h2>
  <p>You can find me all over the Internet!</p>
  <a href="#">Close</a>
</div>

<div id="blog" class="panel">
  <h2>Blog</h2>
  <p>Here are some blog posts.</p>
  <a href="#">Close</a>
</div>

<a href="#projects">projects</a>
<a href="#blog">blog</a>
<a href="#about">about</a>
<a href="#contact">contact</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container { 
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}

.panel{
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
}

.panel:target {
    -webkit-transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
}

.panel#contact {
    transform: translateX(110%);
    background-color:whitesmoke;
}

.panel#about {
    transform: translateX(-110%);
    background-color: red;
}

.panel#projects {
    transform: translateY(110%);
    background-color: blue;
}

.panel#blog {
    transform: translateY(-110%);
    background-color: gold;
}

.panel#contact:target{
    transform: translateX(0%);

}

.panel#about:target{
    transform: translateX(0%);
}

.panel#projects:target{
    transform: translateY(0%);
}
.panel#blog:target{
    transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

Note that the "About" and "Blog" links are transitioning as expected, whereas the "Projects" and "Contact" links appear to cause weirdness. Those are the two with positive values.

I'm having a really difficult time:

a.) understanding what the problem is exactly
b.) how can I fix it (if at all)

If someone could both explain what the browser is doing right now with those erroneous transitions and provide a solution, I would be much obliged.  AFAIK, this is happening in every browser (that supports the :target pseudo element, anyway).

Let me know if you need clarification. Thanks a lot!

UPDATE: Not fixed, but I noticed that if you set the values to <98% for the offending element panels (Projects + Contact), the page transitions properly, though it isn't hidden from the screen.  Not sure what that means, but if it helps...

UPDATE 2.0: Thanks for the comments, folks!  I tried adding a container, and have updated the HTML and CSS to reflect that.  The changes in question are a container div that wraps the panels, as well as the following CSS for that container:

```
.container { 
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}
```

I'm still having similar behavior -- this is also updated in the Codepen.  I think I understand now the issue, but I'm not quite sure why the page is still jumping to that element in question before applying the transformation.  I can imagine there is some hacky way to get around this, but I would rather do it the "right" way.

Comment: click on "Projects" and "Contact" link are doing opposite. I mean when I clean on projects link its shows as of going out of the screen(in top direction). So is this the that weirdness? We have to fix this right?

Comment: That's correct -- apologies for not making it more clear.

Comment: You are forcing an scroll, and this is ruining the visual effect. Try setting the elements inside a container with overflow: hidden

Comment: @vals has got it right. To clarify, the panes are already visible, so if the user jumps to one of them via a link, the browser is trying to scroll it into view first (i.e. in the case of #projects, the viewport jumps down). The only reason that it seems to work as designed for #blog and #about is that the viewport can't jump out of the document.

Comment: Okay, tried adding a container w/overflow:hidden and updated my question to reflect that, but I'm still experiencing the problem of the element being forced into view before the transformation is applied.  I thought maybe it was because I was using vw + vh, but fixed width and height appear to have the same problem as well.  Any ideas to what I'm doing wrong here?  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided that using :target and trying to have this be pure CSS wasn't really the way to go, and wound up just using Javascript in a fairly straightforward manner.

Lesson learned: Don't try to do things w/ Pure CSS unless you really have to.